# C++ tokenise string and store in vector

Tags: c++, string, vector, evaluation

```
vector<string> ExprTree::tokenise(string expression){
     vector<string> store;
     string s;
     std::stringstream in(expression);
while(in >> s) {
  store.push_back(s);

    }

     return store;

}
```

When i input the arithmetic expression (5 + 5) + 5

i get the output:

(5
+
5)
+
5

However i want:

(
5
+
5
)
+
5

Also, the code only separates the strings between whitespaces, is it possible to tokenise a string that is written without whitespaces? i.e (5+5)+5

Comment: It depends how complex is expression you want to parse. You may need regular expression or a more sophisticated parser.

Comment: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/regex/regex_token_iterator

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Split a string in C++?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/236129/split-a-string-in-c)

Comment: Yes, it's possible (but no, a stream won't do the job for you).

Answer (score 0):

2 Updates you can do to solve your problem:

```
string s;
while(in >> s)
//instead, do 

char ch;
while(in >> ch)
```

and then to handle the case of a blank space (and a newline?) put an *if condition*

```
if(ch != ' ')
store.push_back(ch);
```

That is if your desired input are just single digits.
You'll have to make a much complex parser to handle bigger numbers.
To make more complex parsers, this function is helpful. http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/istream/istream/peek/

Answer (score 0):

You can use [strtok](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strtok/), [strtok_r](https://linux.die.net/man/3/strtok_r) or [Boost tokenizer](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_36_0/libs/tokenizer/index.html) to do what you need.

These halp you to split your string by multiple delimiters.

if you want to split string with multiple threads, use strtok_r against strtok.

if you need an example, simply google it.